# Зашифровать строку в javascript

Tags: javascript, шифрование

Есть тест на javascript, вопросы и ответы записаны прямо в коде.
Подскажите какие-нибудь простые алгоритмы, чтобы зашифровать правильный ответ.

```
var questions=[ 
{ 
    text: "Автор книги Код да Винчи:", 
    answers: ["Фил Эшби", 
          "Стив Гамильтон", 
          "Дэн Браун"], 
    correctAnswer: 2 // нумерация ответов с нуля 
}, 
{ 
    text: "Кто является президентом РФ в настоящее время:", 
    answers: ["Д.А.Медведев", 
          "В.В.Путин", 
          "Б.Н.Ельцин"], 
    correctAnswer: 0 
}, 
{ 
    text: "В каком году родился Пушкин А.Н.:", 
    answers: ["1837", 
          "1799", 
          "1873"], 
    correctAnswer: 1 
} 
];
```

Comment: Если расшифровка на стороне клиента, бессмысленно делать сложную схему, умный пользователь оттрасирует и расшифрует всё сам. Поэтому делайте что-то простое, например, прибавляйте к коду символа какую-нибудь простую последовательность (`(23 * i + 79) % 256`, например).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js

Comment: ЕГЭ, простите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совсем просто например, считать остаток от деления, скажем, на 17.

```
correctAnswer = 18; // на самом деле 1
correctAnswer = 153 // на самом деле 0
correctAnswer = 87; // на самом деле 2
```

Проверять:

```
correctAnswer = correctAnswer%17;
```

Если домохозяйка такой квест разгадает, нечего её мучить Ельциным : )

Comment: тут и домохозяйка справится: мы видим три числа, которые по очереди увеличиваются. поэтому можно только на логике догадаться что 18-87-153 на самом деле 0-1-2

Comment: @deivan: числа могут быть любыми по формуле `(17*i + correctAnswer)`, в каждом вопросе с новым i. Ну-ка, продемонстрируйте логику, без калькулятора: где 0, где 1, и где 2 в следующем ряду "правильных ответов":

    1180,1199,952,1217,477,1104,1273,781,610,1140,818,1256,648

Comment: "зачем ви меня тгавите?.." в условии изначально три варианта, а что я вижу у вас?.. 13 вариантов..  это 4 с половиной вопроса? не понимаю, за что ваш ответ выбран лучшим..

Comment: @devian, это как бэ в тесте 13 вопросов, и перечислены значения "правильныхОтветов" к каждому. Все они шифруют некие значения от 0 до 2. В частности, `correctAnswer=2` может быть представлен разными способами, чтобы сбить с домохозяек бигуди. Ну так, прокриптоанализируете без паяльника?

Answer (score 3):

без кода, только алгоритм:

- в поле correctAnswer ставим захэшированный правильный ответ.
- при проверке выбора ответа пользователя - хэшируем ответ пользователя и сверяем с хэшем эталона.
- профит!

естественно, этот принцип можно расколоть, но как защита от домохозяек - вполне сгодится.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Как вы реализовывали хэш-функцию в самом недавнем своём проекте на JS?

Comment: а при чем тут мои проекты?...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант `\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64`

Вбить эту строчку в гугл и все станет ясно!